# how to manually set nvim's data folder

Tags: neovim

I'm currently running out of place for `c:\`

and I found this :
https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/39088
but it seems that the path is written with `%LOCALAPPDATA%`
which means that I can only change it by changing variable `%LOCALAPPDATA%`
it's not a good move I suppose, is there any other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check `:h starting` and `:h base-directories`.

You could probably set these environment variables to fix it:

- `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME`
- `$XDG_DATA_HOME`
- `$XDG_STATE_HOME`

By default they point to `Appdata\Local` in the user profile (home-directory).

`$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR` will by default use your `$TMP`/`%TEMP%`-directory.

If you don't know how to work with environment variables on Windows, check https://superuser.com/questions/284342/what-are-path-and-other-environment-variables-and-how-can-i-set-or-use-them.

Comment: thanks, and it needs to reinstall Mason packages or change executable's path in `nvim-data/mason/bin/*.cmd` after moving `nvim-data`